# Consequences when the commutator is a scalar multiple of the identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I just stumbled over the question below. As to the first, I could easily find out the answer (D) by invoking the commutation relation. But I don't figure out how to solve other two. Could anybody give a hint?

Here's the question:

The commutator

$[B,A] \equiv BA-AB = \lambda I$

of two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ is proportional to the identity matrix $I$.

Choose the only answer for each question.

(1) $[B,A^n]=?\;$ (A) $0\;$ (B) $n\;$ (C) $n\lambda A\;$ (D) $n\lambda A^{n-1}\;$ (E) $n\lambda A^n$

(2) $e^{A+B}=?\;$ (A) $e^{A}e^{B}\;$ (B) $e^{B}e^{A}\;$ (C) $e^{A}e^{B}e^{{1\over 2}[B,A]}\;$ (D) $e^{A}e^{B}e^{[B,A]}$

(3) $e^{A}e^{B}=?\;$ (A) $e^{A+B}\;$ (B) $e^{B}e^{A}\;$ (C) $e^{A}e^{B}e^{[B,A]}\;$ (D) $e^{A}e^{B}e^{-[B,A]}$

Comment: Have you seen this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula

Answer (score 4):

Given the commutation relation $AB-BA=\lambda I$, it is always possible to assume that $A$ is invertible because $(A-\mu I)B-B(A-\mu I)=\lambda I$ holds for all scalars $\mu$. So, without loss of generality, assume $A$ is invertible.

Establish 1(D) by induction: By assumption, $[B,A]=\lambda A^{0}$. Suppose $[B,A^{k}]=\lambda A^{k-1}$ for some $k \ge 1$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
   [B,A^{k+1}]= BA^{k+1}-A^{k+1}B & =(BA^{k}-A^{k}B)A+A^{k}BA-A^{k+1}B \\
     & = [B,A^{k}]A+A^{k}[B,A] \\
     & = \lambda k A^{k}+A^{k}(\lambda I)=\lambda (k+1) A^{k}.
\end{align}
$$
So, by induction, $[B,A^{k}]=\lambda k A^{k-1}$ for all $k \ge 1$.

It is a well-known result that $[B,A]=I$ cannot hold for bounded linear operators on a normed linear space, which certainly includes matrices. To see why, let $\|M\|=\sum_{j,k}|m_{j,k}|$ for an $n\times n$ matrix $M$. Then $\|M_1+M_2\|\le \|M_1\|+\|M_2\|$ and $\|M_1 M_2\|\le \|M_1\|\|M_2\|$ for any two such matrices $M_1$, $M_2$. Assuming the commutation relation for $A$ and $B$, it follows that
$$
    k|\lambda|\|A^{k-1}\| \le \|A^{k}B\|+\|BA^{k}\| \le 2\|A\|^{k}\|B\|\le 2\|A^{k-1}\|A\|\|B\|,\;\;\; k \ge 1.
$$
Either $A^{k-1}=0$ for some $k \ge 1$, which cannot happen because $A$ is invertible, or
$$
          k|\lambda| \le \|A\|\|B\|,\;\;\; k=1,2,3,\cdots,
$$
forces $\lambda=0$, which means $AB=BA$. That makes everything else straightforward.

Comment: In the first line of your induction, the last term should be a $-A^{k+1}B$. But I'm confused about the rest of your answer - I must be missing something, but why can you replace $A$ with an invertible matrix? The proof that $\lambda = 0$ breaks down if $A$ is nilpotent. In fact, if $A = \mu I + N$ for some nilpotent $N$, then by the same reasoning couldn't I assume $A$ was nilpotent?

Comment: Also, the standard proof I know to show $[B, A] = I$ is impossible is just to take traces. This also shows that $[B, A] = \lambda I$ implies $\lambda = 0$, if the field has characteristic zero. But once this is done, shouldn't the "correct" answer to (1) be (A), since $[A,B] = 0 \iff [A,B^n] = 0$ for all $n$?

Comment: @user115654: For some $\mu$, one has $A-\mu I$ is invertible, and the original commutation relation is not changed by that replacement of $A$ by $A-\mu I$. It just shortens the proof. If you show A is nilpotent, then you can show it's 0 by the commutation relation: take the smallest positive $k$ such that $A^{k}=0$, then $[B,A^k]=\lambda kA^{k-1}=0$, which means k=1 or you have a contradiction. .... For the second question, if A and B commute, then, yes, all powers of A and B commute. You needn't go further because the computation of exponentials is trivial when the two commute.

Comment: The commutation relation isn't changed, and I understand why $A$ nilpotent is not a problem (I even gave a different proof above). But the question (e.g. #2, 3) is asking about the original matrices $A$ and $B$, so I'm not even sure if after the replacement step, the question is being answered...

Comment: Well, it is the case that replacing $A$ with $A' := A - \mu I$, and proving $2, 3$ with $A'$ instead of $A$ does imply the statement with $A$. I guess I just had some trouble seeing it at first. But it might be nice to include explicitly

Comment: @user115654: You do believe that I'm able to showing $A-\mu I$ commutes with $B$ for $\mu$ such that $A-\mu I$ is invertible, right? And you do believe there must be such $\mu$, right? Then $A$ commutes with $B$.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the sort of reasoning I was looking for - just wanted to see it spelled out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since this has floated to the front page anyway, let me supply a more elementary answer than the current one.

I assume you work over either the reals or the complex numbers since the question mentions $e^A$.

It is a standard exercise to show that then $AB$ and $BA$ have the same trace, so the trace of $AB - BA$ is $0$, which forces $\lambda = 0$ and hence $AB = BA$.

This immediately gives the answer to all the questions (and in fact means that most of the possible answers are identical).

Comment: It seems worth emphasizing that this analysis goes through because $\text{tr }I$ is finite. For example, one has the identity $[d/dx,x]=1$ with operators $d/dx$ and $x$; from the above, we conclude that these operators can't be represented using finite-dimensional complex matrices.

Comment: @semiclassical And it also fails in positive characteristic, even in finite dimensional cases, with essentially the same example which can be realized in finite dimensions in that case.